# Function that calculates memory reserved in different function

Tags: c, pointers, memory, malloc

I have two functions, one that creates a double array,fill it with zeros and reserve memory for it. The other function 'noarr' is supposed to calculate the memory I have reserved in the 'myarr' function for the array. I'm pretty sure I have successfully filled the array with zeros,
but I am not sure how I can access the array from another function? Am I on the right track of doing it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void noarr(double *** myarr(int n, int m));
double** myarr(int n, int m);

double** myarr(int n, int m){
  int i, j;
  double ** A;

  A = malloc(sizeof(double*)*n*m);

  for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
    A[i] = malloc(m*sizeof(double));
    for(j = 0; j < m; j++){
        A[i][j] = 0;
    }
  }
  return A;
}


void noarr(double *** myarr(int n, int m)){
  printf("%d\n", sizeof(myarr));
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]){  
  int i,j;
  int n,m;
  double (*A)[n];
  A = myarr(n,m);
  printf("%.1f   %.1f \n",A[0][0],A[2][9]);
  noarr(A);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not related but you probably mean `A = malloc(sizeof(double*)*n);` instead of `A = malloc(sizeof(double*)*n*m);`

Answer (score 0):

You simply cannot derive the size of memory (m)alloced somewhere when solely having a pointer to that memory. You need to pass the dimension(s) separately.